# Export a video to a .blend file

Tags: animation, export, edit-mode, video

Yesterday I downloaded an intro template from Youtube and I have now edited it in Blender Video Editing, but I also want to edit the animation in the video. So how can I do this? Can I export the video to a .blend file and open it that way?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, as it currently stands, try adding more info to your question, like a screenshot of what you are trying to do, a link to the video, or the downloaded file. It seems you can't do what you are trying to achieve, you can do minor editing to a video in Blender using the Video Sequence Editor, but if you want to do heavy modification to the animated content you probably have to make your own 3D model and render it from scratch, instead of tweaking an existing one.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve? I'm not much into video editing, but as far as I know you can do some minor adjustments in the video editor like color adjustments, fading and transition effects, overlaying text or other images but that is it. Any further editing requires you to do 3D modeling and rendering footage you can then overlay over your video.

Comment: Here is the video I downloaded from Youtube: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f9vufbct62kqft/intro%20from%20yt.avi?dl=0  As you can see it says' Your Name "in the video, which I want to change. I'll be able to do that through  blender. But how can I open this video in Blender and change it?

Comment: The video is an .avi file, but what I know can you just open a .blend file in Blender, so how should I do now?

Comment: Here is a video with a guy that open a .blend file in Blender and edit the text: https://youtu.be/CfCIDbWdJtw?t=1m21s I want to do same thing with my video, but my video is an .avi file, so I must do it to a .blend file, how?

Comment: In that video the author downloaded a source Blend file, not an AVI video, to achieve that your need to get the source blender file with the 3D scene it was rendered from, not a final video.

Answer (score 1):

AVI is a video container as in a final "presentation" file format, not really an editable or working project file format per-se. You can't just edit the AVI file and replace the text with your own like you would, say, a word document or a text file.

In this case Blender can read the AVI file, use it in the video editor as an external reference, and can overlay stuff over it, like overlaying a new string of text over "Your Name" but not in an automatic way.
You will have to do it manually and integrate it into the video, cut it, move it, and rotate it in a way that blends it in with the animation.

You might want to do that in a 3D scene with 3D objects and then render it, but it is not an easy "press one button" task

Comment: So I can't convert the file to a .blend file and edit the video then?

Comment: No, not immediately. What you need to do is to search for the source file or ask the author if the source Blender file is available somewhere, you can't easily edit that from an AVI file